# Are there other energy bands over the conduction band?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons

I've found this diagram about the conduction band (https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Conduction_band):
[image]

But are there other energy bands over the conduction band? Or is the electron simply kicked out of the solid (and so its energy becomes continuous, not in discountinous band).

Comment: There are many bands, and often overlapping. Below the valence band there are some deeper bands, and above the conduction band there are higher excitation bands. Kicking an electron out of the solid is not shown on the band plot but you can still work it out if you know where the vacuum level is, compared to the energy levels you know.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Do you have sources for this, please? Why don't these higher-energy electrons participate in conduction, then?

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Solid_state_electronic_band_structure.svg is a very standard explanation that is common in textbooks on the subject, and you should be consulting them. They do participate in conduction but they are so few in number that they are completely negligible. Only the many near $E_V$ and $E_C$ really make an important contribution to conduction.

Comment: On the picture you linked, there are only the valence and conduction bands, no band over it.

Comment: The principle is there. You should be able to understand what is happening with just that.

Comment: The hydrogen atom has an infinite number of states below the ionization energy. Similarly, a solid has an infinite number of states below the vacuum level. One generally does not consider them because electrons rapidly thermalize down to states within $kT$ of the Fermi level or conduction band.